# Tagging friends in a fb.api status update?

Tags: facebook, fbjs

Is it possible to tag friends somehow using the Facebook fb.api (JavaScript SDK) call?

By tagging I mean what happens when you use "@" in the regular `facebook.com` UI.

Answer (score 5):

It is currently not possible to tag a friend in a status update or post via the API.

Comment: This is no longer correct. See my comment on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5526793/751

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's what you are asking, but the syntax to tag a friend using Facebook API is `@[uid:friend name]`. However, it seems like there is a bug at the moment and FB does not support it.

Comment: It is not a bug.  That syntax is not documented or supported.

Comment: And now it's documented: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/tagging/#mentions

Answer (score 0):

Check the Facebook documentation for more information about this: *[photos.addTag](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/photos.addTag/)*.

Quote:

> Each tag in the list must specify: "x", "y", and either the user id "tag_uid" or free-form "tag_text" identifying the person being tagged. An example of this is the string {"x":"70.0","y":"70.0","tag_text":"some person"}

And read in *[FB.api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/)* on how to use the REST API calls using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use FB.api to tag a friends.

E.g. If you would like to a tag a friend(s) withing a message that you will share on a Fb's wall you have to do following.

1) Get extended permissions (**'publish_stream'**) e.g. you can request it while login to the app   **FBUser.login({scope: 'publish_stream'});**

2) You have to pass a string with the facebook_user_id to a 'tag' key of the api object. e.g.

**FB.api('me/feed', 'post', {
message: "my message here",
place: '123456789', // mandatory!!!
tags: "123456, 654321, 147258, 852963", // facebook users ids of your friends
name : "Some text here",
description : "Some text here",
picture: "http://wwww.link.to/the_image"})**